# Qt and Boost command line arguments' conflict

Tags: c++, boost, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

In my project there is a Qt application with command line arguments managed by boost. This way, the command line arguments parser manages two specific options (mutually exclusive) "-s" and "-d". If the app is called with both options, it will end with a error code.

Given this background, in order to test it every night we are trying to execute remotely this application through ssh with the following command:

```
ssh user@host /home/user/workspace/project/bin/application -d -style Cleanlooks
```

The "-style Cleanlooks" is intended to run the app with the same Qt style as if the app were run in local computer.

The result is that the  boost parser interprets that both "-d" and "-s" options (plus an additional exception "error: unknown option -t").

Is there any way to send to Qt the "-style Cleanlooks" option and avoid it from the boost parser?

Thanks

Comment: why not use the long-form version for `style`, i.e. `--style`, this should prevent boost from treating `-s` as the short form of the option you are looking for?

Comment: I'm trying what you said, and it is not working :(. I mean, there's a warning message about the boost parsing "Unknown option style" (OK, it's expected), but moreover the Qt style passed by parameter is not applied. Thanks anyway :)